# wrap a virtual method with multiple signatures

Tags: c++, oop, functional-programming, polymorphism, overriding

I have a class with a method which has many signatures (in the example below just two for simplicity).

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void f(int x) const
    {
        std::cout << "A::f(" << x << ")\n";
    }

    virtual void f(int x, int y) const
    {
        std::cout << "A::f(" << x << "," << y << ")\n";
    }
};
```

and a derived class which overrides the methods of the parent class adding some logic before and after the call of the parent's method.

```
class B : A
{
public:
    void f(int x) const override
    {
        std::cout << "B::f(" << x << ")\n";

        // do some stuff before the call
        A::f(x);
        // do some stuff after the call
    }

    void f(int x, int y) const override
    {
        std::cout << "B::f(" << x << "," << y << ")\n";

        // do some stuff before the call
        A::f(x, y);
        // do some stuff after the call
    }
};
```

Since the logic before and after the call of the parent's method is consistent across all the overridden methods, I'm trying to encapsulate all the logic in a function wrapper that takes the method to call as an argument.

```
void wrapper(B const *b, std::function<void() const> &f)
{
    std::cout << "wrapper(" << b << "," << &f << ")\n";

    // do some stuff before the call
    f();
    // do some stuff after the call
}

class B : A
{
public:
    void f(int x) const override
    {
        std::cout << "B::f(" << x << ")\n";

        A const *p = this;
        auto g = std::bind(static_cast<void (A::*)(int) const>(&A::f), p, x);
        wrapper(this, g);
    }

    void f(int x, int y) const override
    {
        std::cout << "B::f(" << x << "," << y << ")\n";

        A const *p = this;
        auto g = std::bind(static_cast<void (A::*)(int, int) const>(&A::f), p, x, y);
        wrapper(this, g);
    }
};
```

There are (at least) two problems with my code,

1. `std::bind` does not generate the desired `std::function<void() const>`
2. if you call the object `g` inside a method `f` of class `B`, the program enters a infinite loop, which I supposed is due to the polymorphism, i.e. the virtual table resolves to `B::f` instead of `A::f`

Do you have any suggestions on how I can fix my code or do you know alternative ways to achieve the goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior for virtual functions, the virtual table HAS TO resolve to `B::f`. The call to an explicit `A::f` from inside `B::f` does not use the virtual table.

On the other hand, if you can put code in `function_wrapper`, you can simply call this function to add your desired behavior then call the parent method:

```cpp
class B : public A
{
public:
  void f(int x) const override
  {
    do_otherstuff();
    A::f(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly how I am handling the task right now, with two methods which are called before and after the parent method call respectively. I was hoping to replace them with one single wrapper function.

Comment: At one point or another you're gonna have to call them anyway. If you really have a long repetitive task, you could always use a macro